# How to exclude a pattern in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've annotated a class as following (it is to be used for WebSocket)

```
"@ServerEndpoint("/myEndPoint")"
```

When I start my web app, I get message like this-

```
03/13/2015 10:37:33.953 [qtp1157136713-20 - ] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/myEndPoint] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler@10dc828b] and 1 interceptor
```

So anytime I send a websocket request, Spring ends up intercepting it. How do I configure Spring to not intercept any URL starting with "myEndPoint" ?

Comment: can you give some more details about how the web app is set up? Is it a Spring MVC project? Do you use Spring Boot? Spring Security? Sample code would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sprint-security.xml, I was able to exclude the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/myEndPoint", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
```

Also look at the link:
http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support

Comment: I don't want Spring to handle this end point at all, with your solution I will need to use Spring WebSocket implementation. I don't want to use Spring at all for web sockets.